# How to join multiple collections using Mongodb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I need to join 3 collections in aggregation with multiple `$lookup`
I tried in C# driver it allow me to `$lookup` User collection but can't perform second `$lookup` for Setting collection.

Anyone can help?

```
db.Transactions.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "Account",
            localField: "AccountId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "Account"
        }
    },
       {
           $lookup:
        {
            from: "User",
            localField: "UserId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "User"
        }
       }
    ])
    .match({
    })
    .project({})
```

here is the C# code:

```
 var account = _dbClient.GetDatabase(_dbName).GetCollection<Account>("Accounts");
var user = _dbClient.GetDatabase(_dbName).GetCollection<User>("Users");
var transaction = _dbClient.GetDatabase(_dbName).GetCollection<Transaction>("Transactions");

var result = (from t in transaction.AsQueryable()
              join a in account.AsQueryable() on t.AccountId equals a.Id
              join u in user.AsQueryable() on t.UserId equals u.Id into userList
              from acc in userList.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where acc.CompanyName.ToLower().Contains(companyName) && c.CreatedDate >= fromDate && c.CreatedDate <= toDate
              select new TransactionHistory
              {
                   Id = t.Id,
                   CompanyName = acc.CompanyName,
                   UserId = u.UserId
                   FirstName = u.FirstName
              }).ToList();
```

I got the error `$project or $group does not support {document}.` using Linq.

Comment: Why not using `LINQ`?

Comment: I need to do some filter such as CompanyName`.Contains()` for Account collection. I tried in `Linq` but it throws me the message say `Containts()` is not supported

Comment: `.Contains(xyz)` is certainly supported...not sure about `Containts()`...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: What do you mean by unable to perform the second `$lookup` ? Could you post a code snippet, also (if any) errors that you're getting?

Comment: @WanBachtiar it does not have any error, it shows the syntax error if I use second `$lookup`

Comment: @JohnB I tried with .Contain() and it works but another problem is using Linq join is inner join. I use .DefaultIfEmpty() but it throw the error: `$project or $group does not support {document}.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I need to join 3 collections in aggregation with multiple $lookup

Given the following classes:

```
public class Transactions
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public int SettingId { get; set; }
}
public class Account
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
}
public class User
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
}
public class Setting
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
}
```

You can perform multiple [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage as below using [MongoDB .NET/C# driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver) (currently v2.9):

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Transactions>("transactions");

var docs = collection.Aggregate()
                     .Lookup("account", "AccountId", "_id", "asAccounts")
                     .Lookup("user", "UserId", "_id", "asUsers")
                     .Lookup("setting", "SettingId", "_id", "asSettings")
                     .As<BsonDocument>()
                     .ToList();

foreach (var doc in docs) {
    Console.WriteLine(doc.ToJson());
}
```

You can add a [Match](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_PipelineDefinitionBuilder_Match__2.htm), in between/before/after if you would like to filter for specific values. Just keep in mind that the documents after altered after each `Lookup` stage.

Worth mentioning that if you need to join multiple collections as part of your common operations, you should reconsider the [database data model](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/). Please see [Schema Design: Summary](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

- Both worked with C#.Net 8 and Mongo Driver 2.24.0
- PS: Both don't support async.
- PS2: 2nd one doesnt allow anonymous return type. Type of return object must be explicitly declared.

Solution 1:

```
IMongoCollection<T> db = database.GetCollection<T>("user");
_companyService.db = database.GetCollection<T>("company");

var result = (from user in db.AsQueryable()
              join company in _companyService.db.AsQueryable() on user.CompanyId equals company.Id into companyJoin
              from company in companyJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join manager in db.AsQueryable() on user.ManagerGuid equals manager.Guid into managerJoin
              from manager in managerJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where user.IsDisabled == false
              select new
              {
                 user.Id,
                 user.Name,
                 user.SurName,
                 CompanyName = company.DisplayName,
                 ManagerName = manager.Name)
              }).ToList();
```

Solution 2:

```
var result = db.AsQueryable<User>()
               .Where<User>( user=> user.Disabled == false)
               .Join<User, Companies, string, 
                    YourCustomResponse>(_companyService.db.AsQueryable(),
                                        user => user.CompanyId,
                                        company => company.Id,                                                                                         
                                        (user, company) => new YourCustomResponse                                                                                       
                                        {
                                             Name = company.Name,
                                             // Other fields in YourCustomResponse
                                        }).ToList();
```