# C# MongoDB driver how to get data from tableId by Id form tableA

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a problem, I just started with MongoDB driver in C# and now I have a tricky question. I have TabA where there's an Id field and I want to get a result which is a combination of the full collection from TabA plus additional result from tables ( name of each record from TabA as combination of "cart/lobId="+ TabA.lobId ).

I understand that it's a poor description, if you'll need some additional info - shoot it.

Tried to use Lookup but didn't understood how to in one request get that expected result, for now first I load all from tabA and after that foreach every item and load data based on lobId paring with "cart/lobId=" plus tabA.Id.

Update, the main problem that I can’t use simple Lookup because name of table is different for every record in tabA , and looks like that problem is not much popular unfortunately ‍♂️

Comment: Please add in your question what have you tried or researched.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57405606/how-to-join-multiple-collections-using-mongodb-c-sharp-driver